# Ajax and status 302

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, http-status-code-302

I'm having a problem with ajax (and/or jQuery ajax) and status 302.

This is what I am trying:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'some_page_that_I_cant_change.php');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(xhr.readyState, xhr.status);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

The `some_page_that_I_cant_change.php` redirects to a `.bin` with `302` code. I do not want to download this file, I just want know the path to the file. Example:

```
./some_page_that_I_cant_change.php
./path/to/bin/file.bin << I wan't only this path as string
```

The problem is that Chrome automatically redirects to the file, without telling me the path to script. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a HEAD request instead of a GET request, I suspect that will do what you want. You should only see headers in the response, no response body (i.e., no .bin will download).

Comment: Thanks. But it don't works on Chrome. It continues to download the file. But, I tried to change to "`async:false`" and have a surprise: the file don't is downloaded, instead, throw a exception `"NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"`. I can't reproduce on jsFiddle, but the header that I want, I can't get too, only simple headers ([code here](http://jsfiddle.net/RL22m/))

Comment: That's silly. Chrome shouldn't download a resource with a HEAD call :-( I haven't got any other ideas honestly, sorry.

Comment: No problems. Thanks anyway. I up too because can help someone with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's an older thread about exactly the same topic with solutions and work arounds:
[How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

**In a word: I don't think you can do that cause of HTTP protocol.**
HTTP protocol([1]:http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) stipulate 302 means redirect URI, and browsers follows.So,the javascript can't get the redirect response, just get final response.

So,You have to get path by response body.